# Change GAC display in Windows Explorer.

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, gac

I've been learning more about the GAC from a fellow developer and I've noticed that our GACs (located at C:/Windows/assembly) seem to be setup differently. One is organized by AssemblyName where you can clearly see the version, Public Key Token, etc. (there aren't any folders). The other, is organized in a folder/file structure - C:/Windows/assembly contains folders for GAC, GAC_32, GAC_64, GAC_MSIL, NativeImages (4 folders with different versions), temp, and tmp.

My machine has the folder/file structure. Is it possible to change this to match the pure file structure so I can easily view the version, token, and other properties?

Comment: The best and least destructive way is to simply unregister the shell extension.  Start an elevated command prompt and navigate to c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework64\v2.0.50727.  Type regsvr32 /u shfusion.dll.  If you want it back then just do this again without the /u option.

Comment: You can simply study the .NET Framework 4.x GAC at `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly`. That shows the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2006/05/05/WindowsExplorerAndTheGlobalAssemblyCache.aspx

I've done the registry one a couple of times.

Regards